# How can get Highlighter.Net 2.0.0.dll

Tags: .net, lucene.net

I need Highlighter.Net 2.0.0.dll for highlight the text. Anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the one in Lucene.NET then [From here](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/download/).